Can I extract PowerBI results to AWS Redshift or RDS for further analysis in AWS?
So now I have powerbi reports and I want to extract the results of any query and store in Redshift or RDS to build an interactive chatbot where I want to build completely in AWS, how can i do that?
I'm curious if that can be done using aws glue or Dataflow gen2
